# Why I cannot use LINQ and IJavaScriptExecutor in Selenium 3.0 and how to solve it?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I use the following specs for my testing:

`Mozilla Firefox 46.1`

`Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1 via Nuget`

`Windows 10 64bit`

Here is my code

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("someURL");
    //error
    var e_email = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("input"))
        .Where(x => x.GetAttribute("name") == "email" 
        && x.GetAttribute("Placeholder") == "Guest Email").FirstOrDefault();

    //also error
    string js = "var paras = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');for(var i=0;i<paras.length;i++) {{ paras[i].parentNode.removeChild(paras[i]);}}";
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(js);
}
```

The above code runs well in `Mozilla Firefox 46.1` and `Selenium 2.53.1`. The errors appear when I update the `Selenium to ver 3.0` and `Mozilla Firefox to ver 47` with [geckodriver 0.11.1](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.11.1.)

It generates `error : Permission denied to access property 'navigator'` for the LINQ and `Permission denied to access property 'document'` for the IJavaScriptExecutor when executed after being updated to newer version. Why should it happen and how to solve this issue?

Comment: there might be some problem with someURL value

Comment: @viveknuna No, because it runs well when I downgrade to the previous version

Comment: Are you using iframe?

Comment: @viveknuna No. I am not using any iframe nor frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue waiting for a fairly complicated XPath in a WebDriverWait and what ended up fixing it was updating Firefox to 49.0.2.